# Ruby: Add value to Variable and Clamp/limit the Variable in one line

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have several arrays in Ruby which I add/subtract values and afterwards I limit their range, like so:

```
array[x][y]=array[x][y]+1


array[x][y]=array[x][y].clamp (0..99)
```

Since I have many different arrays with rather long (index) names - and in order not to repeat those names twice in one line, I'd like to achieve something like

```
array[x][y]+=1.clamp (0..99)
```

Which is accepted by the interpreter, but doesn't work. It adds, but the value in the array does not get clamped.

Splitting it in at least two lines

```
array[x][y]+=1

array[x][y].clamp(0..99)
```

does also add, but doesn't clamp.

Is there any solution for this to fit the entire command in one line?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [`#clamp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp) method doesn't take a range as a single argument for Ruby versions before 2.7, but rather two arguments representing the min and max, and `#clamp` does not mutate the object it's called on.

```
array[x][y] = (array[x][y] + 1).clamp(0, 99)
```

Note that because it's valid to call a method without parentheses, *if* parentheses are used around an argument list, there should not be any space between the method name and the parentheses. E.g. `1.clamp(0..4)` rather than `1.clamp (0..4)`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are fully right. I didn't test out an underflow so far, Passing a range clamps to the max value, but not to the min value.

Comment: Ah, according to

https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/11/24/ruby-2-7-comparable-clamp-with-a-range.html

clamp allows passing a range on 2.7 , However, adding and clamping an array entry with comma separated values in that format you kindly provided leds into "syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'"

Comment: Even in newer Ruby versions where `#clamp` accepts a range, it should still accept the min and max as two arguments.

Comment: Yep, fully right, i made a big mistake - a space between "clamp" and argument. Thank you !

Comment: Happens to the best of us.